# Get content from HTTP POST in php

Tags: php, html, http, post

So I am trying to do something I think should be really simple: sending data using an `HTTP POST` to a simple php script that can take the contained information and do something with it. This information can be either text or image data (binary data), but that is perhaps irrelevant.

I am testing my php script by using `hurl.it` to send a sample `HTTP POST` containing two parameters of `name` and `date` or something simple like that. I have a small php script on the server end that looks for those variable names.

Here is the php:

```
<?php
    echo "Some Message";
    $nameValue =  $_POST('name')
    echo $nameValue
    $dateValue =  $_POST('date')
    echo $dateValue
?>
```

I thought this would work, but I am getting a response stating the following:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in [volume name]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$_POST` is an array. You must do

```
$_POST['name']
```

Comment: I truly could not feel more stupid, I do not know how I did not catch that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

`$_POST['name']` not `$_POST('name')`

also you seem to be missing semicolons.

Answer (score 4):

```
$_POST('name')
```

This should be

```
$_POST['name']
```

`$_POST` is an array, so you use `[]`.  `()` is for functions.

Also, you need to end lines with `;`.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is an associative array. So, as for all associative arrays, the proper syntax is

> $nameValue = $_POST['name'];

Of course, this means that `$_POST['name']` could have been an array itself.